# Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 - Deployment Agent "Unknown username or bad password"

Tags: visual-studio, release-management, ms-release-management

We're using Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 and deployments are working smoothly in DEV, QA and Staging servers, which are all in the same domain as the RM/Build server.

Trying to setup Production deployment agent on a server that is outside the RM server domain and having issues.

A local "shadow" account was created on the RM server and Production server, both with same username/password. Deployment agent was installed on the Production server and setup was successful using "./shadow_user" format for the username.

Release Management client isn't showing the Production server, and Event Viewer on the RM server shows numerous security audit failures from the deployment agent. Failure detail shows the Production server name for the domain instead of the RM server name (impersonation is failing). Specific message is:

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       shadow_User
    Account Domain:     PROD-SVR

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC0000064

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   PROD-SVR
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested
```

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

We've tried Windows Credential manager, using the RM server shadow account credentials, but no difference.

Comment: Have you added both shadow accounts to the RM client (needs to be in machine\account format) and granted **Service User** and **Release Manager** permissions for the RM account and **Service User** permissions for the Production server account?

Comment: Is shadow account in local admin group on prod server?

Comment: @GrahamSmith Yes, both shadow accounts are in admin group (account on Prod and RM server)

Comment: I take it you have seen [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/12/configuring-release-management-to-work-across-untrusted.aspx) piece of documentation? If all those steps have been followed the only other thing I can think of is to try logging on to the prod server with the shadow account to ensure the profile is created.

Comment: Yes, that is actually the same article referenced when setting up deployment agent. Tried logging in with the shadow account and it is valid.

Comment: Try setting up both the shadow account and Windows Credential Manager on the production server.

The article is not up to date.

Comment: @HarshilLodhi Yes, this was already tried. Same error in Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to login with the shadow account on the Production server and add credentials to Credential Manager. Was previously logged in with a different account, and the Deployment Agent didn't see entries in the other Credential Manager instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using shadow account approach .Use VNext release which supports standard deployment (agent less) which will communicate using WINRM port only requirement is to have machines in same network.

for more information:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/07/07/how-to-setup-environments-for-agent-less-deployments-in-release-management-release-management-2013-with-update-3-rc.aspx

Comment: Don't think this is an option, since we already use agent-based template for the lower environments (dev, qa, staging)